# Write vertical text on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

CANVAS:

```
y
a
x
i
s 
 x axis
```

How can I write on a canvas vertically? Ex: the text `yaxis`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way, so you'd have to devise a solution.  I'd write a function that takes in the string and space between characters, then print each one, incrementing the vertical positioning.

An alternative that would be much easier, would be rotating the canvas 90 degrees then draw the text, but that may not be what you're looking for.

Sample code (from codepen):

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillVerticalText = 
  function(text, x, y, verticalSpacing) {
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      this.fillText(text[i], x, y + i * verticalSpacing);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would prefer to do it without rotating the entire canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Just type the text horizontally and press enter after each letter it will go vertical

Comment: Hi. Your solution gives the impression of being a less well explained version of the older and already downvoted answer by Joshua Subayer. Could you point out the additional insight you provide?

Answer (score -2):

Yeah don’t listen to them, that’s real complicated, type what you tryna type... then resize the text box to being thin in width, and it’ll push the letters down vertically

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see what's expected of a complete answer